# Scrolling options in HTML?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pdf, iframe

This is kind of out there, but I am programming an HTML page that has pdfs that I don't want users to be able to download directly. I solved this by getting rid of the pdf toolbar and by overlaying the pdf with an image so that the user can't right-click on the image.

**HTML (React JS)**

```
import BLOCK from "block.pdf";
import PDF from "example.pdf";

...

<div className="PDF">
  <h1>Example PDF</h1>
  <img src={BLOCK} width="100%" height="100%"className="Blocker"/>
  <iframe src={PDF+"#toolbar=0"} width="100%" height="800px" className="Viewer"/> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Blocker{
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.Viewer{
    z-index: 0;
    top: 100px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

However, the issue is now, I can't scroll within the iframe because the image is blocking it too well. Is there a way to transfer the scrolling action to the iframe?

Comment: There's a neat trick to scroll an iframe here: http://www.mesdomaines.nu/eendracht/iframe_scroll_from_main/#explanations.html